# How to update parent key in object - using remote implementation of a method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Rocket interface:

```
interface Rocket {
    name: string;
    setName(name: string): void;
  }
```

Rocket object - applies the rocket interface:

```
const rocket: Rocket = {
    name: 'some-rocket',
    setName: (name: string) => {
      rocket.name = name
    }
  }
```

Now if I want to update the rocket name,
I can do that like this:

```
rocket.setName('new-rocket-name')
```

But as you can see, the setName hardcoded
inside the object itself.
What if I want to put it in a seperate file?
For example:

```
  // set-rocket.ts
  export const setRocket = (name: string) => {
    // how to update the name of the object,
    // which is not available in this scope?
  }
```

I can change the interface and require to
provide with the actual rocket object as
a parameter, but it doesn't look that good:

```
  interface Rocket {
    name: string;
    setName(rocket: Rocket, name: string): void;
  }
```

And then set the rocket name like that:

```
rocket.setName(rocket, 'new-rocket-name')
```

Is there a better way doing it?

Comment: *which is not available in this scope* makes it impossible - the other file needs *some* way to get a reference to the instance, or it can't affect the instance

Comment: Instead of an interface, why not use a class?

Comment: How a class can help with it? can you show?

Comment: or a rocket factory

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by changing the Rocket interface to a class:

```
class Rocket {
  constructor (public name: string) {}
  setName(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
const rocket = new Rocket('some-rocket');
console.log(`current rocket name: ${rocket.name}`);

rocket.setName('new-rocket-name');
console.log(`rocket name: ${rocket.name}`);
```

## A bit more complex example

---

If you want to make the usage of `Rocket` more generic, i.e. you want to create different kinds of Rockets without relying too much on their implementation, we can dive deeper into OOP, and make use of a combination of interface (API) and class (Implementation).

```
interface Rocket {
  readonly name: string;
}

interface ISetName {
  setName: (name: string) => void;
}
```

#### Some implementation

```
class DynamicRocket implements Rocket, ISetName {
  constructor(private _name: string) { }

  setName(name: string) {
      this._name = name;
  }
  get name() { return this._name };
}
```

The advantage of this second method is that you can have different implementations for the `Rocket` interface, while still maintaining the same API for changing their names. So elsewhere in your application, you may have:

```
const updateRocketName = (rocket: Rocket & ISetName, name: string) => {
  rocket.setName(name);
  return rocket.name;
}
```